# Java SE + Apache DeltaSpike: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Repository

Tags: java, repository-pattern, deltaspike

I'm trying to use the [DeltaSpike Data](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/data.html) module with [Weld](https://weld.cdi-spec.org/), but every class annotated with [`@Repository`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.9.3/org/apache/deltaspike/data/api/Repository.html) shows a warning in my IDE and an exception at runtime.

I've tried following the [DeltaSpike documentation](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/) numerous times, checked [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/), and various articles/forums but have not found a solution.

Does anyone know what I might be missing to allow the repositories to be injected correctly?

#### IDE Warning

```
Managed Bean must be a concrete class or @Decorator
```

#### Runtime Exception

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ExampleRepo with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public com.example.myapp.services.ExampleService(ExampleRepo)
```

#### Example Repository

```java
@Repository(forEntity = Data.class)
public interface ExampleRepo extends EntityRepository<Example, Long> {

    Data findExampleById(long id);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Data AS e SET e.locale = ?1 WHERE e.id = ?2")
    int updateLocale(final Locale locale, final long id);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Data AS g SET g.reactTranslation = ?1 WHERE g.id = ?2")
    int updateReactTranslation(final boolean toggle, final long id);
}
```

#### Gradle

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

ext {
    deltaSpikeVersion = "1.9.2"
}

dependencies {
    // DeltaSpike Extensions
    implementation "org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-data-module-api:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-data-module-impl:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-scheduler-module-api:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.deltaspike.modules:deltaspike-scheduler-module-impl:${deltaSpikeVersion}"

    // Database
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:${hibernateVersion}"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:${hibernateVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.apache.deltaspike.distribution:distributions-bom:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
    }
}
```

To clarify, the following are also implicit dependencies of the project.

- [`org.apache.deltaspike.core:deltaspike-core-api:1.9.2`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.deltaspike.core/deltaspike-core-api/1.9.2/jar)
- [`javax.enterprise:cdi-api:2.0`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/2.0/jar)
- [`org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:3.1.3.Final`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jboss.weld.se/weld-se-core/3.1.3.Final/jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a Java SE specific instruction:
https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/cdiimp.html#javase6

I had to use `CdiContainer` from DeltaSpike instead of `SeContainer` from Weld.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl:deltaspike-cdictrl-api:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl:deltaspike-cdictrl-weld:${deltaSpikeVersion}"
}
```